# How to determine my current location (longitude & latitude)?

Tags: php, html, google-maps, geolocation

I currently have php website that I want to be able to find the users current location and then pass that through the url in a format similar to:

```
page.php?lon=2312313&lat=sdfsdsf
```

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: It's not accurate like @Bil_fr already said. One example, I use Romanian IP address (I live in Serbia), ISP has been located ~300 miles eastern. You can't find my location this way (also, this is shared IP). You can use GeoIP database (it costs some money in accurate version) but also you can't deal with IPs like this one I use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing automatic (thank god). You'd be relying on the client to be able to interact with some local GPS device and provide position data. Heavily technology specific.

Answer (score 1):

If the browser supports geolocation, you can do this:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
```

This is an html5 thing, and it will prompt the user the first time to give the site  permission to access your location.

Of course this is a javascript thing (not php)

Answer (score 1):

If you know to identify location name using Google Maps API by supplying latitudes and longitudes, the page that will locate the users is likely to have

`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>`

in its head section

The parameter `sensor=true` suggests that target device has a GPS and the location info will supplied using GPS, as not all mobile web browsers support geolocation. But I'm not sure if this will use BTS (Base Transceiver Station) of mobile service provider to obtain approximate location in case GPS device is not available on phone. Note that entire operation will work using JavaScript instead of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GeoIP PHP library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php) but it's not very accurate.

Comment: This is going to be used on mobile devices so I really need something that can pull from a 3G phone position.

Comment: you'd better go on Android or iPhone heading